# Is it possible to check for all dependent assemblies on compile time in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dependency-management

I understand that the assemblies are loaded in the CLR during compile time and execution begins later,but its possible to throw compile time exception about a missing dependent library of a referenced assembly which is usually thrown at run time?

Answer (score 0):

Compile time:

> When you use compile-time referencing, the compiler automatically gets
>   the public key of the targeted strong-named assembly and places it in
>   the assembly reference of the assembly being compiled.

So it would be stored in the assembly [manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w45z383(v=vs.71).aspx):